# Is there any CMS in nodeJS with customizable back-end?

Tags: node.js, express, content-management-system

I simply need a free open-source CMS to change design, layout and content at the front-end. I want to add payment processes at the back-end like paypal and stripe. It would be good if its in expressJS.

Comment: There is one called jframe.io that works with any platform, including nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to create a new CMS in Node.js using Express.js for creating awesome blogs or shops, at all any website.

Its name is [OpenPress](https://github.com/OpenPress/OpenPress).

You can get news about it [here](https://github.com/OpenPress/OpenPress).

If you have any feature request or improvement, you can send an email to Me or file the issue at the [OpenPress](https://github.com/OpenPress/OpenPress/issues) repository.